# Firefox: How to stop tab tearing mechanism?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

I don't want to be able to drag tabs away from Firefox to produce another instance. I'd like the old behaviour of dragging a tab into explorer to produce a URL shortcut.

I've tried the [Disable Tab Tearing add-on](http://mozillalinks.org/wp/2009/07/disable-tab-tearing-and-six-other-firefox-3-5-tab-tweaks/) but it doesn't seem to work for me - dragged tabs still produce a new Firefox instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be an **about:config** option to disable this, but apparently there isn't.

But the [add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12276) works for me, on Firefox 3.6.
You need to go to Tools > Add-ons and pick the options for the extension, then click the check-box in the dialog.

Comment: This does indeed work, but not if you use Tree Style Tab (http://piro.sakura.ne.jp/xul/_treestyletab.html.en) :(